# Python image cropping number on identity card

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have some identity cards with different resolutions, and I want to crop only the ID NUMBER.
I have a code that crop ID, but fails when the ID is zoomed in or has a different resolution.

```
img = cv2.imread('test.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gray.shape[:2]
center = (w / 2, h / 2)
mid_line = int((center[1]+h)/2-10)
end_point = int((mid_line+h)/2)
mid_vertical_line = int((center[0]/2)+(0.45*(center[0]/2)))
cropped = image[mid_line:end_point, mid_vertical_line:w]
```

and here is the IDs:

correct:

[image: correct]

[image: correct]

wrong:

[image: wrong]

[image: wrong]

wrong:

[image: wrong]

[image: wrong]

Comment: and what's the challenge here? the third card picture is missing pieces of the card. your card detection is already broken... and then you need to properly calculate the region relative to a card. hint: addition of constant numbers has no business in these calculation.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268458/how-to-detect-arabic-number-location-using-opencv